# Nuxt 2 showing Typescript error `Unable to read property 'length' of undefined` on server startup

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, node-modules

I'm building a project using Nuxt v2. It worked fine before. But now when I reinstall the node_module and run `npm run dev`. It will show Typescript error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

[Console log error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhLTj.png)

I'm using Node v14.21.3 and NPM v6.14.18

This is my package file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
    "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.5",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^2.4.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.6.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
    "country-list": "^2.2.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "jquery": "^1.12.4",
    "kentico-kontent-nuxt-module": "^6.1.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.6",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.27.0",
    "nuxt-vuex-localstorage": "^1.2.7",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "twitter-widgets": "^2.0.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "validator": "^13.1.17",
    "vue-masonry-css": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^1.9.0",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.19.1",
    "vue2-google-maps": "^0.10.7",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.14.12",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  }
```

I tried update to Node v14 lastest version. But it's still error

Comment: Have you delete lock file?

Comment: make your question prettier , its not readable easily

Comment: @ByteBrawler0 I also deleted it

Comment: When you deleted node_modules and lock file, have you change versions in package.json file?